# Como posso abrir um modal depois de um evento submit

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Preciso abrir um modal depois que acontecer um submit em um determinado botão, queria saber se tem algum evento para isso, alguma coisa tipo pós submit.

Comment: Quando faz o submit a página faz refresh certo?

Comment: Aham, esse refresh não esta deixando o meu modal abrir.

Answer (score 2):

Aparentemente você esta usando jQuery ai é so usar o [event.preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

algo como

```
$('#meuform').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    //abre a modal aqui
});
```

Isso vai impedir a ação `default` do evento, no caso, envio(`submit`) do form, e vai permitir abrir sua modal.

Como efeito colateral o envio dos dados vai ter que ser feito via ajax.

Existe uma "gambiarra" que dependendo do que você precisa pode funcionar. Consiste em dar um `return false`ao inves de usar o `preventDefault()`, normalmente uso para fazer algum tipo de validacao via js antes do envio.

```
$('#meuform').on('submit', function(event){
    if(!validaForm()){
        //abre a modal aqui
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Eu queria a junção das duas coisas, eu preciso do submit sem dar um refresh na página, se possível sem usar o ajax.

Comment: O proposito do submit é justamente esse, enviar/redrecionar para um endereço, especificado no atributo `action`, os dados do formulario, quando não define um `action` o navegador supoem que é a pagina atual, por isso o refresh. Então não, não existe, que eu saiba, um submit sem refresh da pagina.

Comment: Entendi a sua lógica.

Comment: da uma olhada de novo editei a resposta, dependendo do que precisar pode dar um `return false`, nao sei se é o caso mas vai que...

Answer (score 1):

Uma opção é prevenir que a página seja recarregada usando `event.preventDefault`:

```
$( "#form" ).submit(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $( "#dialog" ).show();
});
```

Comment: Quaseee cara, o problema que agora o submit com o novo Id não acontece, acho que só com ajax mesmo né.

Comment: Sim, é o mais adequado. Você pode fazer o POST por ajax e serializar os dados no envio.